# If $f$ is continuous on $I$, prove $f$ is Darboux integrable on $I$.

Tags: riemann-sum

We are given: Suppose f is a real-valued function defined on the closed and bounded interval $I = [a, b] \subset \Bbb R$. And on the previous problem we proved that for each $\varepsilon > 0$, if there exists a subdivision $\delta$ of $I$ such that $S^+(f, ∆) − S_−(f, ∆) < \varepsilon$, then $f$ is integrable on $I$.

We're told to use the previous result to prove the current one. I'm thinking uniform continuity is the way to go, but am unsure how to approach it. Can anyone give me some guidance on what to do or how to approach this problem?

Comment: I’m confused. Why do you need to be given what $f$ is? Your title says that it is continuous.

Comment: @TedShifrin sorry, I'm sick and not thinking clearly. I was thinking I needed to prove continuity first. I forgot we were given that it was continuous.

Comment: So why did you remove your previous remark? It is the right approach.

Comment: @TedShifrin so I prove uniform continuity to show it's integrable everywhere?

Comment: Well, not "everywhere." Integrable on the closed interval $[a,b]$, yes :)

Comment: @TedShifrin ok, thank you.